# Flutter projects are no longer being provisioned with the lib folder and dart files

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, new-project, android-studio-bumblebee

When i create a new flutter project, the new project is no longer provisioned with the example app, there is no lib folder and no dart files. This has only started happening today. Has there been some update?

Please see screenshots of my new flutter project settings (defaults) and the resulting file structure which has none of the expected files (main.dart, pubspec.yaml) etc...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you looking for `lib`, `pubspec.yaml`, etc inside the `android` folder? The are not there.

Comment: I was simply expanding everything so you could see ALL files that were provisioned... The above is everything... no lib folder, nothing other than what you see... I've literally reinstalled windows, flutter and Android Studio from scratch in my desperation to resolve this and have exactly the same problem... Lib is gone!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm an idiot... through a slip of the finger I had filtered away from 'Project' to 'Android' to the top left of the folder structure...